# Codiginter prevent direct access to method used by form action

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am fairly new to the codeigniter framework, and have encountered an issue I am unsure how to solve properly.

Most of my application requires authentication, but I have one public non authenticated controller for a form. But the uri for the form is encoded with a single use token. So the form can only be accessed once.

The code for my form action...

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('my_form/submit_form' . $id , 'id=”theForm”');
            …
```

I want to prevent someone from accessing/visiting  http://my-site.com/my_form/submit_form/someID and instead throw an  message.  Below is the way I have it working now, but I am not sure if it is secure.  I am using codeigniter's csrf protection, so each $_POST is submitted with a csrf_token.

```
class My_Form extends MX_Controller
{
    …

    public function submit_form($id){
        // my attempt to prevent direct access
        if (!isset($_POST["input_id"])) {
            exit('Sorry this page is inaccessible.');
        }
```

}

So basically if the value of a hidden input field on the form is not set then the script exits. Is this a secure way to handle this?

Comment: Note use array here `form_open('my_form/submit_form' . $id, array('id' => 'theForm'));` You might need to configure your routes.php file the id on form make sure it can match id other wise use `uri segment()` from user guide.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/

Comment: @ Ricky -- How does that address my question.  I am not having any trouble with my form or submitting it,  I only want to make it more secure.

Comment: It is perfectly ok. You can use CodeIgniter way as `$this->input->post() OR exit('Not your cup of tea, buddy.');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public function submit_form($id){
    // my attempt to prevent direct access
    if (!$this->input->post(null, false)) {
        exit('Sorry this page is inaccessible.');
    } else {
        //your code
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks more "codeigniter-esc" thanks.  So I am accepting the answer.